# insert array element into database

Tags: php, mysql

I have this function : it's work correctly,

```
function ms_get_did_detail($id) {
    global $link;
    $q2="select Dest,Priority from destpr where Id='$id'";

    if($res2=mssql_query($q2)) {
        while($row2[]=mssql_fetch_array($res2,MSSQL_ASSOC)) {
            return $row2;
        }

        return 0;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I want insert every element (every Dest & Priority) into MYSQL

```
if($info=ms_get_did_detail($value)) {
    print_r($info);
    $destination = $info['Dest'];
    $priority = $info['Priority'];
    my_did_destination ($priority , $dest , $active , $did_voip , $cc_id);                 
}
```

It returns array like this :

```
[0]=> Array (
    [Dest] => 100
    [Priority] => 1
)
[1]=> Array (
    [Dest] => 200 
    [Priority] => 3 
) 
[2] => (
)
```

also , I have this function to insert value in database :

```
function my_did_destination($priority="",$destination="") {
    global $link_voip;
    $sql="INSERT INTO cc_did_destination (destination,priority) 
          VALUES ('$destination','$priority')";

    $retval = mysql_query( $sql , $link_voip);

    if(! $retval ) {
        die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
    }
}
```

but It's insert empty value within

Comment: make a json from your array and save the json string in db

Comment: how make json from array?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: I am not sure how your ms_get_did_detail function is working. To me it looks like it will get the first row returned from the SELECT and put that into the first position of the $row2 array then return $row2 (with just that single element, irrespective of how many other rows the select would bring back). With your other function, what is the structure of your table? Is the id field an auto increment field?

Comment: yeah, It's auto increment

Comment: Then try to remove the id (and its value) from the insert, or assign it a value of NULL.

Comment: @Kickstart :sure , tnx

Answer (score 1):

You are inserting all rows with an ID of `0`, so, if a row with `id=0` already exists, it will fail and will not be inserted.

Maybe the easiest solution would be to make yout `ID` column `autoincrement` with an SQL statement like:

```
    ALTER TABLE cc_did_destination 
  MODIFY COLUMN id INT auto_increment;
```

And then change your `INSERT` statement for:

```
  $sql="INSERT INTO cc_did_destination (destination,priority) 
             VALUES ('$destination','$priority')";
```

Comment: So, simply change the `INSERT` statement and let us know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your $info is array of rows, it has numeric keys, not 'Dest'.
You should add index, like `$dest = $info[0]['Dest']`.

```
         if($info=ms_get_did_detail($value))
         {
            print_r($info);
            $dest = $info[0]['Dest'];
            $priority = $info[0]['Priority'];
            my_did_destination ($priority , $dest , $active , $did_voip , $cc_id);                 
         }
```

Or you can iterate through `$info` with a loop:

```
         if($info=ms_get_did_detail($value))
         {
            foreach($info as $row) {
              $dest = $row['Dest'];
              $priority = $row['Priority'];
              my_did_destination ($priority , $dest);                 
            }
         }
```

also, remove `id` from your insert statement

Comment: Thank you, how it can be implemented with loop?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues here.

Firstly your first function returns an array of arrays. Ie, it returns an array with subscript 0 for the first row (it only ever returns one rows details), which is an array containing that rows details.

You assign this to the $info variable, so it contains:-

```
[0]=> Array (
[Dest] => 100
[Priority] => 1
)
```

You then assign $info['Dest'] to $destination and $info['Priority'] to $priority. However neither of these exist. You would need $info[0]['Dest'] and $info[0]['Priority'].

2nd issue is that you are trying to assign a specific value to the auto increment id field. Just leave it out of the insert, or give it a value of null.

Quick rewrite and I would suggest you need something like this:-

```
<?php

if($info=ms_get_did_detail($value))
{
    print_r($info);
    foreach($info AS $info_row)
    {
        $destination = $info_row['Dest'];
        $priority = $info_row['Priority'];
        my_did_destination ($priority , $dest , $active , $did_voip , $cc_id);                 
    }
}     

function ms_get_did_detail($id)
{
    global $link;
    $q2="select Dest,Priority from destpr where Id='$id'";
    if($res2=mssql_query($q2))
    {
        if ($row2[]=mssql_fetch_array($res2,MSSQL_ASSOC))
        {
            while ($row2[]=mssql_fetch_array($res2,MSSQL_ASSOC))
            {
            }
            return $row2;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

function my_did_destination($priority="",$destination="")
{
    global $link_voip;
    $priority = mysql_real_escape_string($priority);
    $destination = mysql_real_escape_string($destination);
    $sql="INSERT INTO cc_did_destination (id,destination,priority) VALUES (NULL,'$destination','$priority')";

    $retval = mysql_query( $sql , $link_voip);
    if(! $retval )
    {
        die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

If you want to avoid multiple inserts unnecessarily then it might be easier to use an object. This way you can do the inserts easily when there are enough batched up (I normally do 255 at a time).

Something like this, although you probably should use mysqli_*

```
<?php

if($info=ms_get_did_detail($value))
{
    print_r($info);
    $insert_object = new insert_details($link_voip);
    foreach($info AS $info_row)
    {
        $insert_object->set_row($info_row['Priority'], $info_row['Dest']);
    }
    unset($insert_object);
}     

function ms_get_did_detail($id)
{
    global $link;
    $q2="select Dest,Priority from destpr where Id='$id'";
    if($res2=mssql_query($q2))
    {
        if ($row2[]=mssql_fetch_array($res2,MSSQL_ASSOC))
        {
            while ($row2[]=mssql_fetch_array($res2,MSSQL_ASSOC))
            {
            }
            return $row2;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

class insert_details()
{
    private $db;
    private $insert_row = array();
    public function __CONSTRUCT($db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }
    public function __DESTRUCT()
    {
        $this->do_insert();
    }
    public function set_row($priority="",$destination="")
    {
        $priority = mysql_real_escape_string($priority, $this->db);
        $destination = mysql_real_escape_string($destination, $this->db);
        $this->insert_row[] = "(NULL,'$destination','$priority')";
        if (count($this->insert_row) > 255)
        {
            $this->do_insert();
        }
    }
    private function do_insert()
    {
        $sql="INSERT INTO cc_did_destination (id,destination,priority) VALUES ".implode(',', $this->insert_row);

        $retval = mysql_query($sql, $this->db);
        if(! $retval )
        {
            die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        $this->insert_row = array();
    }

}
```

Quick rough mysqli_* equivalent, assuming that *$link_voip* is a mysqli connection. Note that prepared statements with bound parameters are an option (and it makes it harder to forget to escape variables), but it can become a bit messy when you are doing multiple inserts like this.

```
<?php

if($info=ms_get_did_detail($value))
{
    print_r($info);
    $insert_object = new insert_details($link_voip);
    foreach($info AS $info_row)
    {
        $insert_object->set_row($info_row['Priority'], $info_row['Dest']);
    }
    unset($insert_object);
}     

function ms_get_did_detail($id)
{
    global $link;
    $q2="select Dest,Priority from destpr where Id='$id'";
    if($res2=mssql_query($q2))
    {
        if ($row2[]=mssql_fetch_array($res2, MSSQL_ASSOC))
        {
            while ($row2[]=mssql_fetch_array($res2, MSSQL_ASSOC))
            {
            }
            return $row2;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

class insert_details()
{
    private $db;
    private $insert_row = array();
    public function __CONSTRUCT($db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }
    public function __DESTRUCT()
    {
        $this->do_insert();
    }
    public function set_row($priority="",$destination="")
    {
        $priority = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db, $priority);
        $destination = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db, $destination);
        $this->insert_row[] = "(NULL,'$destination','$priority')";
        if (count($this->insert_row) > 255)
        {
            $this->do_insert();
        }
    }
    private function do_insert()
    {
        $sql="INSERT INTO cc_did_destination (id,destination,priority) VALUES ".implode(',', $this->insert_row);

        $retval = mysqli_query($this->db, $sql);
        if(! $retval )
        {
            die('Could not enter data: ' . mysqli_sqlstate($this->db));
        }
        $this->insert_row = array();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

your array is:

```
[0]=> Array (
    [Dest] => 100
    [Priority] => 1
)
[1]=> Array (
    [Dest] => 200 
    [Priority] => 3 
) 
[2] => (
)
```

so it is a multidimensional array. if you need to insert all those entries, you shouldn't run **multiple queries** for the same thing. just use mysql batch insert syntax. (e.g. `INSERT INTO tbl (col1,col2,col3) VALUES(a,b,c),(d,e,f),(g,h,i)`)

build the query string for insert.

```
foreach($a as $i => $v)
{
   $b[] = '("'.$v['Dest'].'","'.$v['Priority'].'")';
}

$c = implode(',', $b);

$sql = "INSERT INTO cc_did_destination (destination,priority) 
          VALUES ".$c;
```

then run the query

N.B.

[**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: Thank you , but what is $a ?